# Change images with jQuery and remove mainimage to thumbnail

Tags: jquery

Now i click on thumbnail (link_to_thumbnail1.jpg), and the bigger image (link_to_big_image1.jpg) shows inside div with id `#imageWrap`.

**How do i change with jquery the current image inside the div `#imageWrap` with a thumbnail?**

Example: I click on thumbnail 1 (link_to_thumbnail1.jpg), and the current image in `#imageWrap` (Link_to_main_image0.jpg) changes to thumbnail 1, and so on...

I hope, there is a way to solved this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {
            $('#mainImage').hide();
            $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', "url('/ajax-loader.gif')");
            var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
                $('#mainImage').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
                $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
                $('#mainImage').fadeIn();
            });
            return false; 
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="Image" id="imageWrap">    
    <img src="Link_to_main_image0.jpg" alt="" title="" id="mainImage" />     
</div>

<a href="link_to_thumbnail1.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="link_to_big_image1.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
</a>

<a href="link_to_thumbnail2.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="link_to_big_image2.jpg" alt="" title="" />     
</a>

<a href="link_to_thumbnail3.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="link_to_big_image3.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for ? :

http://jsbin.com/avofoj/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
    $('#imageWrap img').empty();
    $('#imageWrap img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what you want to achieve. But if you have a `<div class="imageWrapper"></div>` and you want it to contain something else you can use the `.html()` function like so:

```
$('.imageWrapper').html('<img src="whatever_i_need_to_be_here_now.jpg" />');
```